# Can't remove cursor blinking in console mode

Tags: terminal-emacs, cursor

Emacs 24.3.1, OS: Linux Slackware 14.1.

In my ~/.bash_profile file I have the following:

```
# If on console, change cursor colour according to
# /usr/src/linux/Documentation/VGA-softcursor.txt
# Reset using echo -e '\033[?2c'
if [ $TERM = 'linux' -a $SHELL == '/bin/bash' ] ; then
    echo -e '\033[?17;0;64c'
fi
```

This makes cursor non-blinking and makes it red. When I start Emacs the cursor becomes a blinking dash.

In [Displaying the Cursor](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Cursor-Display.html) chapter I read this:

> On a text terminal, the cursor’s appearance is controlled by the
>   terminal, largely out of the control of Emacs. Some terminals offer
>   two different cursors: a “visible” static cursor, and a “very visible”
>   blinking cursor. By default, Emacs uses the very visible cursor, and
>   switches to it when you start or resume Emacs. If the variable
>   visible-cursor is nil when Emacs starts or resumes, it uses the normal
>   cursor.

So in ~/.emacs I wrote:

```
(setq visible-cursor nil)
```

And restarted Emacs. But it didn't help: the cursor is still blinking, and when I close Emacs it destroys my previous non-blinking cursor.

How to fix?

Comment: How about disabling the global `blink-cursor-mode` with:  `(blink-cursor-mode -1)`

Comment: @lawlist No, doesn't work. I have also tried `(blink-cursor-mode 0)` and `(blink-cursor-mode nil)`. Must be for the graphical mode.

Comment: I think in terminal Emacs has no control over the cursor... You gotta change terminal settings.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but I ran to this issue just today, in Debian 10. Terminals used are Konsole in Debian on the metal and wsltty in WSL.

For me setting `visible-cursor` variable to `nil` worked. The cursor stopped blinking in terminal Emacs. Outside of Emacs, the cursor was not blinking anyway since that's what I had configured. `blink-cursor-mode` was off already too.